# Logical error in timing in C++ (using std::chrono)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

I have written a C++ program to benchmark various sorting algorithms to find out which one is the fastest. However, I am facing some issues while executing my code.

I first created a class to time the algorithms using a constructor and a destructor. I then used `std::chrono::time_point_cast` to explicitly cast the time to milliseconds. However, the program ended up showing zero milliseconds have elapsed every time I run my program.

Please do note that I have included the chrono header file.

Here's the part of the involved program source code.

Class definition

```
int Array[20], size = 20;

class BenchmarkTimer
{
public:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startpt;
    float ms;
    long long duration;
    BenchmarkTimer() : ms(0), duration(0)
    {
        startpt = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    ~BenchmarkTimer()
    {
        auto endpt = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto init = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(startpt).time_since_epoch().count();
        auto final = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endpt).time_since_epoch().count();
        auto duration = final - init;
    }
};
```

Selection Sort function (This is just one of many sorting algorithms).

```
void SelectionSort(int Array[])
{
    BenchmarkTimer timer;
    int temp, smallest, position, j;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        smallest = Array[i];
        position = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (Array[j] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = Array[j];
                position = j;
            }
        temp = Array[i];
        Array[i] = Array[position];
        Array[position] = temp;
    }
    DisplayArray(Array);
    std::cout << "\nTime taken to sort the array: " << timer.duration << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

The `DisplayArray(Array)` function call simply displays the array on to the screen.

I want the program to display the number of milliseconds elapsed.

Right now, the actual output is:

```
Time taken to sort the array: 0 ms
```

But I want the output to be:

```
Time taken to sort the array: 13 ms
```

(13 ms is just an example.)

I would suggest you to suggest simpler solutions, as I am in the intermediate level of C++ programming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes I did. I even tried using ````nanoseconds````.

Comment: You calulate the duration in the destructor and the destructor hasn't been called yet when you call `timer.duration`. Move the destructor code in a function called `get_elapsed_time()` that return the attributes `duration`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that you only do you time calculation in `BenchmarkTimer`'s destructor.  This means `duration` will always be 0 since it only changes in the destructor and you can't access the object after it gets destructed.

There are a few ways to fix this.  The first is to just move the timing code into the function.  Secondly you could modify `BenchmarkTimer` to take a function object in the constructor that will be the code to run and then do your calculations in the constructor.  That would look like

```
class BenchmarkTimer
{
public:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> startpt;
    float ms;
    long long duration;
    template<typename Func>
    BenchmarkTimer(Func func) : ms(0), duration(0)
    {
        startpt = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        func();
        auto endpt = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto diff = end-start;
        duration = diff.count();
    }
};

void SelectionSort(int Array[])
{
    BenchmarkTimer timer([&]()
    {
        int temp, smallest, position, j;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            smallest = Array[i];
            position = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
                if (Array[j] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = Array[j];
                    position = j;
                }
            temp = Array[i];
            Array[i] = Array[position];
            Array[position] = temp;
        }
    });
    DisplayArray(Array);
    std::cout << "\nTime taken to sort the array: " << timer.duration << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Another option would be to add another function to `BenchmarkTimer` that you call once you want it to do the calculations, and move your destructor code into there.  Take care with that as in your destructor you declare a `duration` variable that hides the class's `duration`.  The code should be something like

```
auto endpt = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto init = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(startpt).time_since_epoch().count();
auto final = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endpt).time_since_epoch().count();
duration = final - init;
// ^ no auto here
```

Comment: I wish I could incorporate this suggestion, but I found it to be a bit advanced. I rather found rafix07's suggestion to be a more simpler, yet feasible alternative. However, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MithunK No problem.  Hopefully one day you'll look at this code and not think it is so advanced.  If you are curious, we have a great list of books [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that discuss modern C++ and templates.  They are worth reading at some point.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way to address this is to just put the print statement for the timer in `~BenchmarkTimer()`.  The `BenchmarkTimer` constructor could take a message to augment the output in `~BenchmarkTimer()`.  This might look like:

```
class BenchmarkTimer
{
public:
    std::string msg_;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startpt_;

    explicit BenchmarkTimer(std::string msg)
        : msg_(std::move(msg))
        , startpt_(std::chrono::steady_clock::now())
    {
    }

    ~BenchmarkTimer()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto endpt = steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << msg_ << duration_cast<milliseconds>(endpt - startpt_).count() << " ms\n";
    }

    BenchmarkTimer(BenchmarkTimer const&) = delete;
    BenchmarkTimer& operator=(BenchmarkTimer const&) = delete;
};
```

You would use it by constructing a `BenchmarkTimer` at the point where you want to start timing, with an appropriate message, and it will record and log the time for the scope of the timer.  For example:

```
void SelectionSort(int Array[])
{
    BenchmarkTimer timer{"\nTime taken to sort the array: "};
    int temp, smallest, position, j;
    // ...
    DisplayArray(Array);
}  // Output: Time taken to sort the array: 13 ms
```

Comment: What is the use of the ````explicit```` keyword?

Comment: It prevents a `std::string` from implicitly converting to a `BenchmarkTimer`.  Instead _explicit_ syntax must be used as shown in the example use within `SelectionSort`.  I should probably also modify my answer to give `BenchmarkTimer` deleted copy members since it would be unusual (and likely a bug) to extend the lifetime of a `BenchmarkTimer` object.